# fetchall returns stdClass object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, db2, odbc

I'm executing a query to a db2 ibm database in Laravel.

```
call STOREDPROC.GET('leaders', '{"params": ""}', 'lead_management', 'FR');
```

The problem is that the fetchAll() returns an array of stdClass object.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [noref] => 368 
        [nofab] => FORT 
        [actionname] => FORT BP720 
        [longactionname] => Epargne fort 
        [startat] => 1999-10-29 
        [endat] => 1999-10-29 
        [monthduration] => 0 
        [kam] => CTER 
        [cls] => SDO 
        [status] => O 
        [deletebyte] => 
    )
)
```

That's nice and all, but I'd rather get an array instead. I have to send the data through a http request and unfortunately, the data received at the other end of the request returns as a stream.

So how do I make fetchAll return an array instead of an stdObject class ?

I have tried to edit the options in the database.php file in laravel as such:

```
'options' => [
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
],
```

But it still gives me the exact same result.

This is my code to fetch the data in laravel:

```
private function execute($verb, $args): array
{
    $query = $this->buildQueryString($verb, $args);

    $this->buildConnection();

    $result = DB::connection('odbc')->select($query);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: If you're using eloquent you can use [toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray)

Comment: @Andrei  {"message":"Call to a member function toArray() on array","status_code":500}

Comment: You're already fetching an array. Change your PDO settings to fetch class. You can use individual fetch mehods per query.

Comment: Show the code you're actually using to get the results, please.

Comment: @Andrei still gives the same error

Comment: @aynber i updated my question, but i doubt it'll help

Comment: Ok, so you're not using eloquent to do the query. Then it's a different story. I suppose you can do a json_encode -> json_decode to get an array.

Comment: @Andrei  {"message":"Return value of App\\Power\\StoredProcedure::execute() must be of the type array, boolean returned","status_code":500} for some reason it returns as false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was the encoding on special characters causing syntax errors and thus invalid formatted json. I have made it to work by converting to utf8 encoding and then a json_decode instead of encode.

```
public static function convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($result)
{
    if (is_string($result)) {
        return utf8_encode($result);
    } elseif (is_array($result)) {
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($result as $i => $d) $ret[ $i ] = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($d);

        return $ret;
    } elseif (is_object($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $i => $d) $result->$i = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($d);

        return $result;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And then in my response:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Unfortunately, this PDO setting is deep in the kernel of the framework and cannot be changed. I had to write not so good code to get out of this situation:

```php
foreach ($result as $key => $item) {
    $result[$key] = (array) $item;
}
```

Comment: your solution works with print_r() but if i just do echo, it says that the value must be an array, boolean given, status code: 500

Comment: It seems the problem was the encoding on special characters causing syntax errors and thus invalid formatted json. I have made it to work by converting to utf8 encoding and then a json_decode instead of encode.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$result = json_encode($result);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: "{\"message\":\"Return value of App\\\\Power\\\\StoredProcedure::execute() must be of the type array, null returned\",\"status_code\":500}"

Comment: What is the type of $result before using json_encode? Can you use **dd** function for getting it in the client (Please post part of the result here)?

Comment: with dd($result) i'm getting a giant stream

Comment: It seems the problem was the encoding on special characters causing syntax errors and thus invalid formatted json. I have made it to work by converting to utf8 encoding and then a json_decode instead of encode.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for PDOStatement::fetchAll () is PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT.
This behavior can be changed with PDOStatement::setFetchMode () giving as argument one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants.

This is what Laravel does, it changes the default behavior by calling PDOStatement::setFetchMode (PDO::FETCH_OBJ). This is done in Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepared () by calling setFetchMode ($this->fetchMode) where attribute $fetchMode (class Illuminate\Database\Connection) has initial value PDO::FETCH_OBJ.

So, all you have to do is to change in class definition this $fetchMode attribute from PDO::FETCH_OBJ in PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT. I have tested this in my Laravel 8.77.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).